# issue using simpleDialogue2

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to create a simpleDialog2 using the code below:

```
function deleteItem(itemID) {

  $('<div>').simpledialog2({
    mode: 'button',
    headerText: 'Are you sure?',
    headerClose: true,
  //  buttonPrompt: 'Please Choose One',
    buttons : {
      'Delete': {
        click: function () { 
          //$('#buttonoutput').text('OK');
        }
      },
       icon: "delete",
      'Cancel': {
        click: function () { 
         // $('#buttonoutput').text('Cancel');
        },
        theme: "c"
      }
    }
  })
}
```

And I get this error every time `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('<div>').simpledialog2')` And help you can provide would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was actually that I hadn't imported the simpleDialog2 statements in the correct order, as this [page](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos2/install.html) outlines.